VMWare Workstation - Changing subnet settings for host-only network from Class C to Class B ( 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0) on Windows Host
I have followed the instructions from the VMware page that explains how to Add a Host-Only Virtual Network to my configurations, but I also want to change the subnet mask for my new interface. I have tried to follow the instructions provided from another doc, but I get an error when attempting to modify the subnet mask to class B or 255.255.0.0. For instance, the network settings I want to use are within the range 10.8.241.0/16. This works with no problem in VirtualBox:

however, I receive the error notice win Vmware when I attempt to apply the same kind of settings:


Does anyone know why this is the case? I am not aware of any network files that I could manually modify on a Windows 10 host machine as described in Linux systems from here or here

the answer and justifications were offered from the official VMware forum at this post.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
